# Bug in fadeIn transition for first image in the carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel of 4 images using the jQuery fadeIn transition. The first image of the carousel does not smoothly fade in after its previous animations are over.

Here is a link to the web page:
https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/St.Anthony-Website/

How to fix this issue?

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="images/page-1-hero-image.jpg" alt="school's image" class="img-responsive page-one-pic mySlides">
    <img src="images/Capture2.jpg" alt="school pic" class="img-responsive mySlides">
    <img src="images/Capture.jpg" alt="school pic" class="img-responsive mySlides">
    <img src="images/Capture3.jpg" alt="school pic" class="img-responsive mySlides">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var imgs = $(".slideshow > img");

function carousel() {
    imgs.hide();
    imgs.each(function(index,element){
        // Don't make the first one (index = 0) wait at all;
        // make the second (index = 1) wait 3 seconds, the third
        // (index = 2) wait 6 seconds, etc. And then fade in
        $(element).delay(index * 3000).fadeIn(1000);
    });
    // Start the entire process again two seconds after the last image fades in
    setTimeout(carousel,imgs.length*3000);
}
```

Link to github repository : https://github.com/rimildeyjsr/St.Anthony-Website

Comment: http://lab.25sprout.com/fadeImg/ have a look.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

By default all images are visible and overlapping each other. When one slide fades in the old one is visible and new one comes above it. So, you see a smooth transition.

When you restart transition then you are hiding all images and fading first image. At that time there is no old image in back so, background (white) of body is being visible and transition is not looking good.

Solution: you need to manage z-index of images. So, when last image ends you need to keep it visible. Change z-index of first image larger then last image. and then fadeIn first one. (make sure you don't hide the last image.